# View Group Permissions does not show all URLs

Tags: 2013, permissions

When i open a particular Sharepoint Group and click on settings->View group Permissions i get the URLs where the group has access.

In the list it also shows some pages it has access. However not all pages are mentioned. The group has permissions on those pages. But it does not show in view group permissions

Comment: Those pages which are not shown are located in the same library than the visible ones? Is the library permission inheritance broken? Are we talking about SitePages or PublishingPages?

Comment: The pages are in same Library "Pages". Inheritance is not broken, all the pages have same permission.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce this behaviour with explicitly shared pages (SP 2013 Standard)

1. create testpage_1, check-in & publish
2. break inheritance of pages library
3. create testpage_2, check-in & publish
4. share testpage_2 with permission_group
5. reset inheritance of pages library

After this steps surprisingly the view group permission windows shows a permission for testpage_1 whereas testpage_2 is not listed!
Due to the resetted library permission we don't assume at first glance that there are explicit shares on pages.

So to me it seems that this view has problems to investigate the current permissions. And it handles explicitly shared files or pages differently than pages with inherited permissions.

If I'm asked whether we can trust the proposition of this window? Perhaps not (or not in this version I've tested it).

For the sake of completeness: in my test collections publishing feature is activated (not sure whether this lovely devil has side effects here too).